# How can I convert ActionResult to List in C#

Tags: c#, list, actionresult

This is function from my partner:

```
public ActionResult<string> ReadSmb(string server, string share, string path, string username = "", string password = "")
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        NTStatus status;
        SMB1Client client = new SMB1Client(); // SMB2Client can be used as well
        bool isConnected = client.Connect(server, SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
        if (isConnected)
        {
            status = client.Login(String.Empty, username, password);
            if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                List<string> shares = client.ListShares(out status);
                ISMBFileStore fileStore = client.TreeConnect(share, out status);
                object fileHandle;
                FileStatus fileStatus;
                if (fileStore is SMB1FileStore)
                { path = @"\\" + path; }

                status = fileStore.CreateFile(out fileHandle, out fileStatus,
                    path,
                    AccessMask.GENERIC_READ | AccessMask.SYNCHRONIZE,
                    SMBLibrary.FileAttributes.Normal, ShareAccess.Read,
                    CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN,
                    CreateOptions.FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | CreateOptions.FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT,
                    null);

                if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        byte[] data;
                        long bytesRead = 0;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            status = fileStore.ReadFile(out data, fileHandle, bytesRead, (int)client.MaxReadSize);
                            if (status != NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS && status != NTStatus.STATUS_END_OF_FILE)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Failed to read from file");
                            }

                            if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_END_OF_FILE || data.Length == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            bytesRead += data.Length;
                            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        }

                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(932)))
                        {
                            result.Append(streamreader.ReadToEnd());
                            streamreader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AppendLine($"file open : {status.ToString()}");
                }
                status = fileStore.CloseFile(fileHandle);
                status = fileStore.Disconnect();

                client.Logoff();
            }
            else
            {
                result.AppendLine($"logon : {status.ToString()}");
            }

            client.Disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            result.AppendLine($"not connected : {server}");
        }

        return Json(result.ToString());
    }
```

And The results he tried displayed on the screen as follows:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
ActionResult<string> test = TestFunction();
List<string> list = test;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
{
     //do something with list
}
```

My "ActionResult test" is return Json(result.ToString());

And now, i want to convert from ActionResult to List to loop them and do something with them.

How can I convert or do any thing to loop them?

Thanks for read my post :)

Comment: You mean [this ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? What is the scenario in which this needs to be done?

Comment: @Omar Abdel Bari
I want to loop and count lines of return . thank you for read my post :)

Comment: What is the result, can you post the whole action pls? And how do you call it from another action too.

Comment: `ActionResult<string>` implies that you would get a run time error if you tried to cast test to a `List<string>` AFAIK. You would be trying to convert a `string` into a `List<string>`, Which is incompatible. You would need to deserialize `test` first. And I feel like you are likely approaching whatever you are trying to do the wrong way. This is why I suggest adding the business logic you are trying to implement and the helpful community can give you some alternatives to make your life easier.

Comment: @Serge, Omar Abdel Bari
I just updated the question . Can you read again my post ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: It's still not clear how you went from `string` to `List<string>` unless there is a line separator in that string that you did not mention and you want each item to represent a separate line.

Comment: @Omar Abdel Bari I just update full funtion . Can you read again my post ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: or can you edit something in my partner's function to return List<string> ?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code (I'm sure you've already seen it before asking the question, but maybe did not read carefully) and [edit] question to show just necessary information - i.e. in your case replacing whole content of the sample code shown in the question with string constant (like `result = new StringBuilder("Resulting string I have problem with")` would make code much easier to understand also show what you expect "the list" to contain (indeed that should match the string value in the code)

Answer (score 1):

Genuinely? You wouldn't do it this way

It looks like the method from your partner is either supposed to be in a controller directly,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> ReadSmbstring server, string share, string path, string username = "", string password = ""){
  ...
}
```

or the controller method is some hollow shell/passthrough like,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get(...){
  return ReadSmb(...);
}
```

It's going to be harder to work with ReadSmb the way it is, than changing it so it just returns a string, and then passthrough calling it in a controller:

```
public ActionResult<string> ReadSmb(string server, string share, string path, string username = "", string password = "")
{
    ...

    return result.ToString();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get(...){
  return Json(ReadSmb(...));
}
```

Also, I do want to point out that it's going to be hard to work with all round, because it basically prepares what looks like a block of formatted text. There's barely any point in "JSONifying" that, because all it'll do is wrap it in `"` and turn any `"` inside it into `\"`

`Json()` is intended to work with objects like:

```
var r = new Person {
  Name = "John",
  Age = 22,
  Address = new Address {
    Street = "Infinite Loop",
    City = "Cupertino"
  }
}
```

And it'll churn out

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 22,
  "address": {
    "street": "Infinite Loop",
    "city": "Cupertino"
  }
}
```

If you made `ReadSmb` return you some sensible object then it'll be a lot easier to work with, and `Json()`ing the result will do something reasonable which makes it a lot easier to work with at the other end of the pipe

If ReadSmb returned you a class like:

```
public class SmbFile{

  public string FileName {get; set;}

  public string Status {get; set;}

  public string B64Content { get => Convert.ToBase64String(_fileContent); }
  [JsonIgnore]
  public byte[] FileContent { get; set;} //note, properties should not return arrays - doing for convenience of demonstrating a point
}
```

Then you could inspect the Status, know if there was some bytes data, read it, parse it, whatever youre planning on doing.. and it would `Json()` fairly sensibly too